# How can i show correct last login date time in website?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a asp.net website, that we are going to deploy at India. All client of this website would be from SWEDEN.

This site have option (last login date time) at user's dashboard after successfull login.

Now my problem is that if application is deploy at India and user loggedin from SWEDEN then user is able to show only server date time which is of India.

My Steps are as following

```
1. User logged into site first time at 10 AM(server time), surfing starts...
2. Logged out at 10:30 (server time)
3. Application store server datetime in database.
4. Next time user come, application will store same date and time from database as last loggin datetime.
```

How can i store SWEDEN date time in database when user logged out from site, it will in future grow to other country also.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to store dates as UTC and convert to the user-timezone when you want to display it.
Maybe this link is useful as a starter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx (Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo)

Answer (score 0):

Store LoginDateTime in UTC.

Determine the time-zone from IP or store user country in USerProfile information in your database.

Transform UTC datetime to UserPreferred timezone while display.

Comment: Thanks,

Can u have any line of codes as an example. It would help me.